# How to use callback with useState like setState in class components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a table of rows of text fields that the user can edit, and also add new rows. When the user clicks the 'Add' button to add a new row, I want to set the focus on the first text field of the last row, the row that was just created. Here is some sample code:

```
interface Row {
    id: string;
    desc: string;
    firstTextFieldRef: React.MutableRefObject<undefined>;
};

const defaultRow: Row = {
    id: '',
    desc: '',
    firstTextFieldRef: useRef(),
};

const [rows, setRows] = useState<Row[]>([Object.assign(defaultRow, {})]);
```

When the user clicks the addRow button, I invoke this function:

```
const addHandler = () => {
    setRows([...rows, Object.assign(defaultRow, {})]);

    // use setTimeout because setRows^^ is async and rows aren't updated immediately
    // other solutions exist, but this works ok for now
    setTimeout(() => {
        const ref = rows[rows.length - 1].firstTextFieldRef;
        if (ref.current) ref.current.focus();
    }, 100);
};
```

I want to avoid using setTimeout here. I am aware that I can use useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ref = rows[rows.length - 1].firstTextFieldRef;
    if (ref.current) ref.current.focus();
}, [rows]);
```

But, adding a new row isn't the only time that the rows array changes. The rows array gets updated anytime the user types into an input in a row.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that and removed my comment. Looks like I completely misremembered.

Comment: Ha yeah no worries, I wish it had that, like setState!

Comment: `Object.assign(defaultRow, {})` makes no sense

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I guess I just use that to create a new instance of the object, but I don't think it is affecting my problem here. I think ```{...defaultRow}```, would be equivalent,

Comment: But it doesn't create a new instance. It returns the `defaultRow` object itself. The equivalent to that spread syntax would be `Object.assign({}, defaultRow)`. But I guess it works because you don't *need* to copy the instance, every render call creates a new object anyway and probably also your row updates don't use mutations.

Comment: @Bergi Ah yeah, I see. Then you are right. This is a very silly statement, I'll change that. Thanks!

Comment: @Bergi What do you use in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

> But, adding a new row isn't the only time that the rows array changes.

If you don't care about row changes, but only changes to the array length (i.e. new rows), use that to trigger the effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ref = rows[rows.length - 1].firstTextFieldRef;
    if (ref.current) ref.current.focus();
}, [rows.length]);
```

Comment: Ah this is a great idea. But the user can also delete rows. I could maybe throw an if statement in here to check if the length is one greater than before? I still feel like there should be a better way with hooks.

Comment: I'd probably model it completely and add a `focusedRowIndex` state.

Comment: Yeah I figured that might be necessary. I'm technically relying on a ref being created in the rows array as well, but it seems to work.

If you want the acceptance, change your answer to that and I'll accept.